# Reorganizing app.js to put related initialization steps together

Tags: javascript, node.js, express.js

This is my app.js:

```
'use strict';
global.config = require('./config/environment/config');
global.i18n = require('./config/locales/config');

var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.locals = global.config;

var passport = require('passport');
var session = require('express-session');
var load = require('express-load');
var flash = require('express-flash');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'))
    .set('view engine', global.config.site.html.engine)
    .set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000)
    .set('env', process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development')
    .set('ip', process.env.IP || "0.0.0.0")

app.use(favicon(__dirname + '/assets/favicon.ico'))
    .use(logger('dev'))
    .use(bodyParser.json())
    .use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))
    .use(flash())
    .use(cookieParser())
    .use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'assets')))
    .use(session({ secret: 'keyboard cat' }))
    .use(passport.initialize())
    .use(passport.session());


var middlewares = require('./middlewares/config')(app);

load('models')
    .then('controllers')
    .then('routes')
    .into(app);

var prototypes = require('./helpers/prototypes');

mongoose.connect('mongodb://' + global.config.db.credentials + '@' + global.config.db.url + '/' + global.config.db.name, function(req, res) {
    console.log('db ok');
});

module.exports = app;
```

One aspect that annoys me is that I would prefer to have all the `require()` calls together.  However, if I move `middlewares` and `prototypes` before `app.set()`, the code will break.  Is there a better way to organize this code?

Answer (score 1):

You can always move the `require()` call for middlewares up. You're not doing anything with the returned value from calling it on `app`.

```
var middlewares = require('./middlewares/config');

app.set(.....)

app.use(.....)

middlewares(app)
```

I'm assuming `prototypes` does some hacks with the global namespace. If so, then there's not much you can do about it. That's not really good practice though.